# Smart SVN Folder permission

Tags: smartsvn

I am using smartsvn on windows and i have wordpress site configured with that, but i have 2 issues,

When i make changes on my local machine and commit it reflects after 1 day, i don't know why 1 day delay,

Also recently i am having issue with upload folder , due to folder pemission i can not upload image and i don't know how to change folder permission

```
define('CHMOD', '777');

chmod -v 746 DIR
chmod -v 747 DIR
chmod -v 756 DIR
chmod -v 757 DIR
chmod -v 764 DIR
chmod -v 765 DIR
chmod -v 766 DIR
chmod -v 767 DIR
```

Comment: Please give more details on what you are actually doing. What happens on your machine? What on the server? How do you think will SmartSVN folder permissions (on your local machine) relate to your wordpress problem?

Comment: local machine i have folders that is linked with SVN, but when i go to admin on live website and upload any image it shows permisssion error and do not create any folder in upload folder for eg. 2017

Comment: Also if i change any code in local and commit it reflects on next day